# Should we consolidate rain forecast questions?

Tags: discussion

There are many questions about how to interpret rain in the weather forecast.  Some are focused on the PoP, some are focused on the amount, while others are focused on trying to find a relationship between the two.  Most are new users trying to figure out what the forecast really means.  I would like to suggest that we consider these as duplicates and consolidate them to one question.  The revised question would be comprehensive in nature...  something like "How should I interpret the rain forecast?" It would mean migrating good answers, which I think is possible. And we would probably get some good new answers.  Here are the questions that are similar in nature:

- [How to interpret hourly precipitation forecast?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/4511/how-to-interpret-hourly-precipitation-forecast?rq=1)
- [I'm still confused about what "probability of precipitation" means](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/17478/im-still-confused-about-what-probability-of-precipitation-means?rq=1)
- [How to interpret precipitation probability?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/18594/how-to-interpret-precipitation-probability?rq=1)
- [Intuitive explanation of precipitation amount](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/3132/intuitive-explanation-of-precipitation-amount?rq=1)
- [What does a mm of rain mean?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/14587/what-does-a-mm-of-rain-mean?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [What do weather forecasters mean when they say "50% chance of rain"?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/70/what-do-weather-forecasters-mean-when-they-say-50-chance-of-rain?rq=1)
- [Relationship between Probability of Precipitation and Predicted Amount of Rain](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/22552/relationship-between-probability-of-precipitation-and-predicted-amount-of-rain?rq=1)

Do people like this idea?  Or is this too much micro-managing?

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr:** *Go for it!*

"A good idea" and "micro-managing" are not necessarily always exclusive ;-)

*Closing* as duplicates is the standard procedure, *merging* is rare, but I think that's mostly due to trepidation by mods, so if you are willing to do so are there any down sides to merging?

The only one I can think of is a loss of question content, and that can be mitigated by carefully crafting (or editing) the target question.

In meta, my question [Have there been analyses to see if views of well-received answers are reduced by closure as duplicate which try to control for other factors?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/366884/303080) is well-received but currently unanswered.

> ...my concern has been that fewer future eyes will reach that good answer due to the closed status.

My hunch is that just closing n-1 questions *does reduce visibility* of otherwise good answers to them, **and a well-done merger can have substantial long-term benefit by boosting visibility of all the good answers.**

Answer (score 1):

I think the idea was nice in theory, but in practice there were some differences in what was actually being asked.  All in all, I merged one question about what rainfall amount is with another, which migrated the one answer that was with the duplicate post.  I also changed the title question of some of the probability of precipitation questions because they were asking something a little different (despite the titles being almost the same intent).  I was left with a couple posts that I think could be called duplicates, but they are rooted in specific examples so I left them alone.